# How do I skip videos in the Portal 2 co-op?

Tags: portal-2

Is there a way to skip the videos in beginning of co-op play and the videos between hub and chamber?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are at a loading screen if you can't see each others messages and in-game when you can.

During the video in the beginning of co-op play you can talk, which means that you are in-game. You can use this time to chat with your friend in advance, but if you play regularly with someone you know this can indeed be annoying. While trying around yesterday I have noticed that you can influence the settings of the co-op game.

**Thus the video in the beginning can be skipped by changing the host time scale:**

1. `sv_cheats 1`
2. `host_timescale 16` (if it works, it should up the video by about 16x, shouldn't take long)
3. `host_timescale 1` (Set it back, or you'll be unable to play the game properly)

These server-side settings are adopted to the other player, so you'll see them executed twice.

**The videos between the hub/chambers can't be skipped**, because they are *loading* screens.

**Notice:** You can *not* get achievements for that game anymore...

Comment: Does this disable achievements as well?

Comment: @Bora: Achievements are only disabled during the time period that `sv_cheats` is enabled, as it checks that variable when it is about to assign an achievement.

Comment: Looks promissing, i'll take a look at evening

Comment: @Mailo: You can speed it up by putting 1/2 and 3/4 in two binds. :)

Comment: @Tom In the first Portal, achievements were disabled entirely once you started cheating unless the game was restarted (or through a complicated pausing/saving/loading precedure).  Which makes sense because otherwise you could do everything except the last step via cheating, then switch off cheats. Have you tested this method?

Comment: @MatthewRead: Perhaps it's still like that, I think I misread a FAQ I found earlier. Well, I'll adjust my answer.